# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when iterating through MutableList in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I have an application that iterates through a list of locations and determines whether or not the user is within a perimeter around each of those locations. When I was using SharedPreferences to store the data I didn't have this issue, but now that I've switched to an SQLite database, I've been getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` on the following loop. The stack trace points to the first line of the loop.

```
loop@ for (i in locationList) {
                val distance = getLocationFromReminder(locationList[iterator], currentLocation).toDouble()

                // If the user distance is within the radius distance...
                if (distance <= locationList[iterator].radius) {
                    when (locationList[iterator].inside) {
                        null -> { // WHEN DISTANCE <= RADIUS AND LOCATION IS SET TO NEITHER INSIDE NOR OUTSIDE
                            locationList[iterator].inside = true // Set inside to true
                            locationList[iterator].entered = getTransitionTime() // Set entered to the entrance time
                            addToTransitionArray(iterator, locationList[iterator].entered, true) // Add entrance time to entrance time array
                            // db.addLocationTransition(locationList[iterator], getTransitionTime())

                            sendNotification(this@MapsActivity, "Fence created around current location.", reminder.latLng)
                            val logMessage = "[${getDate()}] Fence created around current location (${locationList[iterator].message}) at ${getTimeStamp()}."
                            logMessage(logMessage)
                            refreshLocationList()
                        }
                        false -> { // ...and reminder.inside == false...
                            locationList[iterator].inside = true
                            locationList[iterator].entered = getTransitionTime()
                            addToTransitionArray(iterator, locationList[iterator].entered, true)

                            // db.addLocationTransition(locationList[iterator], getTransitionTime())
                            locationList[iterator].entranceNoteArray.add(locationList[iterator].entranceNoteArray.size, "-")


                            val logMessage = "[${getDate()}] Entered ${locationList[iterator].message} at ${getTimeStamp()}"
                            logMessage(logMessage)

                            // Send notification
                            sendNotification(this@MapsActivity, "Now entering ${locationList[iterator].message}!", locationList[iterator].latLng)
                            sendSnackbar("Transition logged at ${locationList[iterator].entered}.")
                            refreshLocationList()
                        }
                    } // Otherwise, if the user's distance from the Reminder is farther than its radius...
                } else if (distance > locationList[iterator].radius) {
                    when (locationList[iterator].inside) {
                        null -> { locationList[iterator].inside = false }
                        true -> { // ...and reminder.inside == true...
                            // Notify user that they are exiting perimeter
                            sendNotification(this@MapsActivity, "Now exiting ${locationList[iterator].message}!", reminder.latLng)
                            locationList[iterator].exitNoteArray.add(locationList[iterator].exitNoteArray.size, "-")

                            // Get transition time for most recent exited
                            locationList[iterator].exited = getTransitionTime()
                            locationList[iterator].inside = false
                            addToTransitionArray(iterator, getTransitionTime(), false)
                            addToTimeInsideArray(iterator, getTimeInside(locationList[iterator]))

                            val logMessage = "[${getDate()}] Exited ${locationList[iterator].message} at ${getTimeStamp()}"
                            logMessage(logMessage)
                            sendSnackbar("Transition logged at ${getTimeStamp()}.")
                            refreshLocationList()

                        }
                    }
                }
                iterator++
                continue@loop
            }
```

Here's the Reminder class that the locationList MutableList is populated with, for some context:

```
class Reminder : Serializable {
    @SerializedName("address") var address: String = ""
    @SerializedName("city") var city: String = ""
    @SerializedName("state") var state: String = ""
    @SerializedName("zip") var zip: String = ""
    @SerializedName("latLng") var latLng: LatLng = LatLng(0.0, 0.0)
    @SerializedName("radius") var radius: Double = 0.0
    @SerializedName("message") var message: String = ""
    @SerializedName("inside") var inside: Boolean? = null
    @SerializedName("tableList") var tableList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("")
    @SerializedName("tableName") var tableName: String = "LOCATIONS${message}"
    @SerializedName("entered") var entered: String = "00:00"
    @SerializedName("exited") var exited: String = "00:00"
    @SerializedName("timeinside") var timeInside: String = ""
    @SerializedName("allentrances") var allEntrances: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("")
    @SerializedName("allexits") var allExits: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("")
    @SerializedName("timeinsidearray") var timeInsideArray: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("")
    @SerializedName("entrancenotearray") var entranceNoteArray: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("")
    @SerializedName("exitnotearray") var exitNoteArray: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("")
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int = 0 // NEW
}
```

I understand that I probably shouldn't be using an integer to iterate through this MutableList, and I understand that the issue is caused by this loop,

I know there are similar questions to this, but they all answer the question in the context of Java, and I want to know if there is something different that should be done with Kotlin, or, otherwise, what the best approach is. I see people talking about using iterators, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what the exact cause of this issue is or how to fix it.

If there's some documentation on the Kotlinlang site that I haven't found that would help me with this, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: "if there is something different that should be done with Kotlin" - no. The problem and the solutions are the same.

Comment: @OrangeDog Surely you understand why I might ask this, considering things like nullability are handled a little differently in Kotlin. Kotlin streamlines some things; that's why I specified it.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, actually. I hadn't found this one even though I was going through the similar questions on the question creation page - maybe I missed it. Thanks.